# Animate resize of view without resizing button inside view

Tags: android, animation

I have a Linear Layout which I want to be animated to resize when I click on it. Once it is resized you should be able to see buttons and text. I've tried animating using this:

```
container.animate().scaleX(scale);
container.animate().scaleY(scale);
```

Also I tried this:

```
container.startAnimation(anim);
```

where anim is (for making the view bigger):

```
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="10.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="10.0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:duration="700" />
```

But the problem is that each time I resize the LinearLayout the children inside get resized as well. This should be compatible to AndroidSDK 16 and above. How to achieve **[this](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsaDBfZWtha0RwNGM/animation-responsiveinteraction-materialresponse-PointOfOrigin_DO_003.webm)** without resizing the children inside?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can override onMeasure() method of the children and make its dimensions as constants for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
float scale = 1.2f;
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,100); 
animator.setTarget(container);  
animator.setDuration(1000).start();  
animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener()  
{  
    @Override  
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)  
    {   
        LayoutParams layoutparams = container.getLayoutParams();
        layoutparams.height = (int)(layoutparams.height* animation.getAnimatedValue() *(scale -1f));
        layoutparams.width= (int)(layoutparams.width* animation.getAnimatedValue() *(scale -1f));
        container.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    }  
});
```